# How to convert a float into uint8_t?

Tags: c++, arduino, lorawan

I am trying to sent multiple `float` values from an arduino using the LMIC lora library. The LMIC function only takes an `uint8_t` as its transmission argument type.

`temp` contains my temperature value as a float and I can print the measured temperature as such without problem:

```
Serial.println((String)"Temp C:         " + temp);
```

There is an example that shows this code being used to do the conversion:

```
uint16_t payloadTemp = LMIC_f2sflt16(temp);
// int -> bytes
byte tempLow = lowByte(payloadTemp);
byte tempHigh = highByte(payloadTemp);
payload[0] = tempLow;
payload[1] = tempHigh;
```

I am not sure if this would work, it doesn't seem to be. The resulting data that gets sent is: `FF 7F`

I don't believe this is what I am looking for.
I have also tried the following conversion procedure:

```
uint8_t *array;
array = (unit8_t*)(&f);
```

using arduino, this will not even compile.

something that does work, but creates a much too long result is:

```
String toSend = String(temp);
toSend.toCharArray(payload, toSend.length());
payloadActualLength = toSend.length();
Serial.print("the payload is: ");
Serial.println(payload);
```

but the resulting hex is far far too long to when I get my other values that I want to send in.

So how do I convert a `float` into a `uint8_t` value and why doesn't my original given conversion not work as how I expect it to work?

Comment: You mean you want to convert a `float`'s binary representation into a sequence of `uint8_t`s? That's where your explanation seems to lead, even though your stated question is for converting a `float` to a single `uint8_t` (e.g. `uint8_t x = static_cast<uint8_t>(temp)`). *Just wanted to check that if I corrected that, I would not be changing the intent of your question.*

Comment: I did ask about a single, you are correct, In the end, I hope to have the temp, humidity, and a few other readings part of it, but I am right now trying to get my head around just converting 1 value before I get into getting them all in some array.

Comment: I have a nagging doubt that you did not grasp the point of my question. I am focusing on temperature; the "humidity, and a few other readings" might as well not exist as far as this line of inquiry goes. You are saying you do want a single `uint8_t` to transport the temperature? Not the two bytes you use with `tempLow` and `tempHigh` (which are assigned to the first two bytes of `payload` and later reported as `FF` and `7F`)? Not the four bytes you would need to avoid data loss when coming from a 32-bit `float`? How much of the temperature data do you need to keep?

Comment: I am hoping to keep 2 digits after the decimal, so 20.02. I don't need anything after that.
I am worried that one of the large issues here is I don't fully understand what a uint8_t is.

Comment: If you don't understand what a `uint8_t` is, you should reword your question in terms of things you do understand. Someone has edited your question to say that `uint8_t` is required by the API you are using -- if that is accurate, keep it, but state your goals at a higher level. Some suggestions: 1) Describe what you have on the sending side (already mostly done, but add the expected range of values). 2) Describe what you want on the receiving side (such as keeping two decimal digits after the decimal point). 3) Describe what your tools, including the API, allow you to do.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are trying to figure out a minimally sized representation for these numbers that you can transmit in some very small packet format.  If the range is suitably limited, this can often best be done by using an appropriate fixed-point representation.

For example, if your temperatures are always in the range 0..63, you could use a 6.2 fixed point format in a single byte:

```
if (value < 0.0 || value > 63.75) {
    // out of range for 6.2 fixed point, so do something else.
} else {
    uint8_t bval = (uint8_t)(value * 4 + 0.5);
    // output this byte value
}
```

when you read the byte back, you just multiply it by 0.25 to get the (approximate) float value back.

Of course, since 8 bits is pretty limited for precision (about 2 digits), it will get rounded a bit to fit -- your 23.24 value will be rounded to 23.25.  If you need more precision, you'll need to use more bits.

If you only need a little precision but a wider range, you can use a custom floating point format.  IEEE 16-bit floats (S5.10) are pretty good (give you 3 digits of precision and around 10 orders of magnitude range), but you can go even smaller, particularly if you don't need negative values.  A U4.4 float format give you 1 digit of precision and 5 orders of magnitude range in 8 bits (positive only)

Answer (score 0):

If you know that both sender and receiver use the same fp binary representation and both use the same endianness then you can just memcpy:

```
float a =  23.24;
uint8_t buffer[sizeof(float)];

::memcpy(buffer, &a, sizeof(float));
```

Comment: I just attempted this, It gives me the output: 00 00 00
I find this a bit odd as I thought floats were 4 bytes, not 3 I am not sure what is going on.

Comment: your data is actually 2 bytes long

Comment: @Kevin192291 it can't be `3`. Print `sizeof(float)` to see what it actually is. How are you printing the array?

Answer (score 0):

In Arduino one can convert the float into a String

```
  float ds_temp=sensors.getTempCByIndex(0); // DS18b20 Temp sensor
```

then convert the String into a char array:

```
  String ds_str = String(ds_temp);
  char* ds_char[ds_str.length()];
  ds_str.toCharArray(ds_char ,ds_str.length()-1);
  uint8_t* data =(uint8_t*)ds_char;
```

the uint_8 value is stored in `data` with a size `sizeof(data)`

Answer (score 0):

A variable of `uint8_t` can carry only 256 values.  If you actually want to squeeze temperature into single byte, you have to use fixed-point approach or least significant bit value approach

- Define working range, T0 and T1
- divide T0-T1 by 256 ( 2^8, a number of possible values).
- Resulting value would be a `float` constant (working with a flexible LSB value is possible) by which you divide original `float` value X:  `R = (X-T0)/LSB`. You can round the result, it would fit into byte.
- On receiving side you have to multiply integer value  by same constant `X = R*LSB + T0`.